# After Fardh salah saying a wazifah then blow on your fingers and rub your eyes Sunnah?

Tags: sunnah, islamic-basis, muslim-practices, bidah, sufism

Some Muslims after a Fardh Salaah recite a wazifah (Allah's name or Ya Nur or Quranic ayah) so many times you then blow on your fingers and rub over your eyes. Virtue of doing so is Allah will strengthen your eyes and protect them from seeing haraam.

Is this proven from the sources or bid'ah please?

Answer (score 1):

Bismi Allah Ar Rahman Ar Rahim.

In the name of God, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful.

All Perfect Praise be to Almighty God,

and prayers and peace be upon the Messenger of Allah and his family and companions,

Having said that,

Peace be upon those who follow guidance

The Sunnah is that the Muslim should say after every Fardh prayer

1- "استغفر الله Astaghfero-Allah" (ask forgiveness of Allaah) //three times.

2- "اللهم أنت السلام ومنك السلام تباركت ياذاالجلال والإكرام Allah-uma anta Assalam Wa minka Assalam tabarkta ya dha Aljalali wa Alikram"(O Allah,you are the most peaceful, peace be from you,  bless you with all glory and honor)//one time

3- "لا إله إلا الله وحده لا شريك له ، له الملك وله الحمد وهو على كل شيء قدير . لا حول ولا قوة إلا بالله . لا إله إلا الله ، ولا نعبد إلا إياه ، له النعمة وله الفضل وله الثناء الحسن . لا إله إلا الله ، مخلصين له الدين ولو كره الكافرون . اللهم لا مانع لما أعطيت ، ولا معطي لما منعت ، ولا ينفع ذا الجد منك الجد"there is no god except Allah, and we do not worship except Him, He has grace, and He has the merit, and He has good praise. There is no god but God, faithful to him religion even if the unbelievers hate, O God, there is no objection to what was given.

4-"سبحان الله والحمد لله ، والله أكبر" (Praise (Uniqueness) be to Allah and praise (Thankful) be to Allah and Allah is Great) Thirty three times each, and says on the 100th : "لا إله إلا الله وحده لا شريك له، له الملك وله الحمد وهو على كل شيء قدير" (There is no god but Allah alone and no associate, He has The Reign and Praise , and He is capable of all things).

5-After the prayer of Maghrib and Al-Fajr say the following: "لا إله إلا الله وحده لا شريك له ، له الملك وله الحمد يحيي ويميت ، وهو على كل شيء قدير"(There is no god but Allah alone and no associate, He has The Reign and Praise and He gives life and death, and He is capable of all things) //ten times

6-Read Ayat Al-Kursi (verse 255 of Surat Al-Baqarah) //one time

7-Read Surat Al-Ikhlas + Surat Al-Falaq + Surat Annas //one time each (three times each after Al-fadjr and Al-maghrib prayers)

This is what most of the evidence indicates regarding dhikr after fardh prayer - but what you did mention about rubbing eyes there is no mentioning of it from our Prophet's -Prayers and peace of Allah be upon him- heritage

and God knows best.

Comment: We are not a site for preaching, or for proving which interpretation of Islam is "more correct". All users here are expected to treat each other, including each others beliefs, with respect; as such, please refrain from inserting rhetoric into your answers that's hostile to other belief systems, no matter how much you may disagree with them.

Answer (score 1):

there is NO authentic evidence for blowing onto ones fingers and wiping the eyes with them after making fardh salah or making dua.

Al-Shuqayri (may Allaah have mercy on him) mentioned the bidah of kissing the thumbnails and wiping the eyes with them after making duaa following salaah, or bunching the fingertips together and touching them to the eyes after prayer, and reciting certain things whilst doing so; he said that these are silly innovations.

(Al-Sunan wal-Mubtadaaat, p. 71)